# How to get rid of wp-login.php in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I have a Wordpress blog site. But I see the wp-login.php file allows users to access Wordpress admin section even though I have restricted the "wp-admin" folder by a folder protection. Can I simply delete this file off? My users of the site are not allowed to log into the site form the blog. Please let me know if there is any issue if I delete this .php file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not good practice to remove login file, rather you can use plugins to rename your wp-admin or wp-login.php to something else you wish to use.

Use [Rename wp-login.php](http://wordpress.org/plugins/rename-wp-login/) plugin to rename your site's login address from:

```
http://www.example.com/wp-admin
```

to

```
http://www.example.com/securelogin
```

Answer (score 3):

No problem if you delete this, but you have more ways to get rid of this.

Check [**This**](http://wordpress.org/plugins/rename-wp-login/) plugin if you want to rename login address.

Also read **[This](https://web.archive.org/web/20140122073006/https://managewp.com/change-your-wordpress-login-url)** article.